# How to get smooth text-to-speech of sentence with utterance ids

Tags: android, kotlin, text-to-speech

My goal is to use the [Android Text-to-speech API](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/tts/TextToSpeech) play a sentence of text as speech while tracking the currently spoken word.

To get a smooth natural playback I use:

```
tts.speak("This is the sentence", TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null, null)
```

but then I can't keep track of the currently spoken word.

To play the sentence while keeping track of the currently spoken word I use:

```
val words = "This is the sentence".split(" ")
words.forEachIndexed { index, element ->
    tts.speak(element, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_ADD, null, index.toString())
}
```

combined with an UtteranceProgressListener, but then the speech is very jerky and not read back as a natural sentence.

Is there a way to get both a naturally spoken sentence and at the same time keep track of the currently spoken word?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you look in the latest Android documentation you will notice a new method introduced to the UtteranceProgressListener in API level 26 - called onRangeStart((String utteranceId, int start, int end, int frame)

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/tts/UtteranceProgressListener.html#onRangeStart(java.lang.String,%20int,%20int,%20int)

However, as the documentation states:

"Only called if the engine supplies timing information by calling rangeStart(int, int, int)"

This is implemented in the SynthesisCallback:
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/tts/SynthesisCallback.html#rangeStart(int,%20int,%20int)

Again documentation states:

"The service may call this method to provide timing information about the spoken text."

So, sadly this means that the callback providing the timing information you need is implementation dependant.

On my device running Android 8.0.0 and using the default tts engine (com.google.android.tts) I did not get the callback.

In order to test you will need to

- to build against SDK level 26 or above
- Implement your own UtteranceProgressListener
- Set it to the TextToSpeech engine by calling TextToSpeech.setOnUtteranceProgressListener(listener);
- Override the onRangeStart(String, int, int, int) method in your
  UtteranceProgressListener.

If your implementation supports the timing information you will the callback, if not perhaps your best bet is to find another engine implementation or perhaps implement your own TextToSpeechService.

Comment: For onRangeStart(), I am facing an issue if the text that I am trying to speak has punctuations like full stop, question mark and exclamation mark. The issue happens if the text is a paragraph with multiple lines. onRangeStart() stops sending start, end and frame data once it encounters any of the above mentioned punctuations so the callbacks from onRangeStart() method are unreliable.